# -2 reputation on answer when question is removed

Tags: support

The author of a question named [Organizing uploaded media according to the post's publish date (not current date)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74663/organizing-uploaded-media-according-to-the-posts-publish-date-not-current-date) just removed the question. The 'title' popup says "Voluntarily removed". You can still see it in [Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Kw0umXFzSNIJ:wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74663/organizing-uploaded-media-according-to-the-posts-publish-date-not-current-date) though I don't know for how long. I had an answer to that question with no upvotes (at least per Google's cached copy). When the author removed the post it triggered, or seems to have triggered, a -2 reputation for me.

[image]

That is the part I am curious about. It is as if my answer to the question is considered voted down. The -2 is not a big deal but I am curious about the logic, and I haven't been able to find anything that explains it.

I see a similar thing on a post named ["Custom e-mail: How is preference decided"](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:owSkinYjFR4J:wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73521/custom-e-mail-how-is-preference-decided), which seems to have been removed by community/moderator action, but with that one I didn't have an answer, just a comment, which makes even less sense (at least to me).

What is the logic behind -2 for comments and answers on removed questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that it doesn't say anything about it being your *answer*. This loss is of +2 rep that you gained from editing *question* - which you can see in your reputation log for Dec 5.

Comment: That is a possibility I had not thought about. Thank you sir. It all makes sense now.